# From where can I get Malayalam translation of Srimad Bhagavatam?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

If possible I would like ISKCON's book.

Comment: You may use your own discretion here, but I would highly discourage you from reading anything from ISKCON. They interpret the texts to their own whims and biases. Go for transliterations/translations by reputed Acharyas; preferably one that was published at least a century ago. I think many translations of the Bhagavatam exist that were published with a charter from the Tirunal of Travancore: look at those.

Answer (score 3):

[Srimad Bhagavatam](https://archive.org/details/Srimad_Bhagavatam_Malayalam_Anvayakrama_Paribhasha_sahitam/) by Paribhasha Sahitam in Malayalam or by [MN Ramaswamy Iyer](http://www.malayalamebooks.org/2016/08/srimad-bhagavatam-malayalam-12-volumes/)

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing two videos which I found , both  are important and will be informative for you because it demonstrate the books with page view.

Both are in Malayalam itself

1. Best with story style
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KEFa3Khnu4&t=0s
2. Multiple books
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0e6e9AN9tU

Answer (score -2):

You can get it from [Wisdom Books of India](https://wisdombooksofindia.com/product/srimad-bhagavatam-full-set-malayalam/). There are 18 parts/volume. The author is A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada and book is published by  Bhaktivedanta Book Trust.